# Entity Framework MySql: DbGeometry not read from the DB

Tags: mysql, entity-framework

I have a this model:

```
public partial class UserPosition
{
    ...
    public DbGeometry Position { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

I create this object and save it to the MySql DB (db is my DBContext):

```
var pos = new UserPosition
{
    ...
    Position = GeographyHelper.CreatePoint(request.Latitude, request.Longitude),
    ...
};

db.UserPositions.Add(pos);
db.SaveChanges();
```

GeographyHelper.CreatePoint:

```
/// <summary>
/// Creates a DbGeometry point from latitude and longitude values
/// </summary>
/// <param name="latitude"></param>
/// <param name="longitude"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static DbGeometry CreatePoint(double latitude, double longitude)
{
    var text = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat, "POINT({0} {1})", longitude, latitude);

    // 4326 is most common coordinate system used by GPS/Maps
    return DbGeometry.PointFromText(text, 4326);
}
```

The value is perfectly saved to to DB:

```
POINT (19.038934 47.531)
```

But when I read the value from the DB, the Position is null, other fields are OK:

```
var rec = db.UserPositions.FirstOrDefault()
```

I get the right record because the ID matches.

Why is the Position null?

Visual Studio 2015, .NET 4.5.2, EntityFramework 6.2.0, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6 6.9.12, MySql database version: 5.6.15.

Answer (score 0):

It was globalization problem: decimal point was saved to the DB but couldn't parse the same geometry data when read because decimal comma was needed (for `Double.TryParse()`) because of the globalization. The fast solution was to set the globalization to en-US in web.config but I accept if you know better solution :)

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <globalization uiCulture="en-US" culture="en-US"/>
    ...
```